# how does the pow function work in glsl?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm following the website: https://thebookofshaders.com/05/

I'm working on this code now but I can't seem to understand how the pow function is making the line change when I plug in different values into the function:

```
// Author: Inigo Quiles
// Title: Expo

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265359

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

float plot(vec2 st, float pct){
  return  smoothstep( pct-0.02, pct, st.y) -
          smoothstep( pct, pct+0.02, st.y);
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;

    float y = pow(st.x, 1.5);<-- 1.5 what is it doing exactly? how does changing the values make the line change in relation to the st.x value?

    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    float pct = plot(st,y);
    color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Hence, for now stuck with the pow function and how changing the values works in relation to the st.x value

Comment: Have you read the spec? https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/pow.xhtml... so it's say `10 ^ 1.5` - if you don't understand this, then see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/how-to-calculate-a-decimal-power-of-a-number

Comment: `10` was an example of what `st.x` could be. `st.x` could be anything.

Comment: Okay thank you for your feedback and help.

I guess my math is weak so I'm struggling with this. Do you advise I go back to basics and learn math and then come back to this journey?

Comment: Ridiculous that this question was closed as off topic. The question and the excellent answer is an example of how good stackoverflow can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that's computing the line is arguably this code

```
float plot(vec2 st, float pct){
  return  smoothstep( pct-0.02, pct, st.y) -
          smoothstep( pct, pct+0.02, st.y);
}
```

since it's only using st.y I think it might be easier to understand if written like this

```
float one_if_a_is_close_to_b_else_zero(float a, float b){
  return smoothstep(a - 0.02, a, b) -
         smoothstep(a, a + 0.02, b);
}
```

That code is used to choose between 2 colors. One color is

```
color = vec3(y);
```

which will be a shade of gray

The other color is `vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` which is green

This line chooses between those two colors, gray or green

```
color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

It *might* be easier to understand like this

```
vec3 gray = vec3(y);
vec3 green = vec3(0, 1, 0);

// choose gray when pct is 0
// green when pct is 1
// and a mix between them when pct is between 0 and 1
color = mix(gray, green, pct);
```

So all that's left is choosing `pct` so let's rewrite that too.

```
// st.x goes from 0.0 to 1.0 left to right across the canvas
// st.y goes from 0.0 to 1.0 up the canvas
float a = st.y;
float b = pow(st.x, 1.5);
float pct = one_if_a_is_close_to_b_else_zero(a, b);
```

Rather then using `pow` you could try a few replacements

```
float b = st.x;  // same as pow(st.x, 1.)
```

or

```
float b = st.x * st.x;  // same as pow(st.x, 2.)
```

or

```
float b = st.x * st.x * st.x;  // same as pow(st.x, 3.)
```

knowing that st.x goes from 0 to 1 it should be clear that `pow(st.x, 1)` will give you a straight line and `pow(st.x, 2.0)` will give you a curved line. Just do the math `b = st.x * st.x` for various values of `st.x` bewteen 0 and 1

```
  0 *   0 = 0.00
 .1 *  .1 = 0.01
 .2 *  .2 = 0.04
 .3 *  .3 = 0.09
 .4 *  .4 = 0.16
 .5 *  .5 = 0.25   // we're half way between 0 and 1 but the result is only .25
 .6 *  .6 = 0.36
 .7 *  .7 = 0.49
 .8 *  .8 = 0.64
 .9 *  .8 = 0.81
1.0 * 1.0 = 1.00
```

Comment: Okay makes sense, seems like I'm just struggling with the math. Which means I should go back to the basics and learn some math and come back to this journey?

Comment: fake it til you make it!